# Error: `siteUrl` does not exist on `siteMetadata` in the data returned from the query

Tags: reactjs, metadata, gatsby, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sitemap

I'm getting an error when trying to run `gatsby build`, everything works fine with `gatsby develop`.

The error I get:
[Error: `siteUrl` does not exist on `siteMetadata` in the data returned from the query.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifvj3.png)

My config-gatsby file:

```
const siteMetadata = {
  title: 'title',
  description: 'descritption',
  author: '@author',
  siteUrl: 'https://example.com',
};

module.exports = {
  /* Your site config here */
  siteMetadata,
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-sass',
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-page-creator`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
        ignore: [`page.jsx`, `page.jsx`],
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-sitemap',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-robots-txt',
      options: {
        host: siteMetadata.siteUrl,
        sitemap: `${siteMetadata.siteUrl}/sitemap/sitemap-index.xml`,
        policy: [{ userAgent: '*', allow: '/' }],
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

I work with multiple people on different branches of git. After I got the error someone else tried it on the branch I'm working on and get the same error. The error occurred after doing 'npm install'. Everything worked fine before.

I have searched for a solution for many hours but it seems like this error isn't very common, can't find much about it.

What have I tried so far:

- deleting cache, node_modules, package-lock.json
- downgrading npm/node versions (also reinstalling)
- gatsby clean
- rewritten the config file to a basic version with a query in the options and a resolveSiteUrl function

Steps to reproduce:

Follow Part 1: Create and Deploy your first gatsby site from
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-1/

Make sure you don't install any CMS or styling system. Only install the `gatsby-plugin-sitemap` plugin.

The clipboard after installing the new gatbsy site:

```
  System:
    OS: Linux 4.4 Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
    Shell: 5.0.17 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.18.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.17 - /mnt/c/Users/senad/AppData/Roaming/npm/yarn
    npm: 6.14.15 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/bin/npm
  Languages:
    Python: 2.7.18 - /usr/bin/python
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^4.2.0 => 4.2.0
    gatsby-plugin-sitemap: ^5.2.0 => 5.2.0
```

I am using gatsby on WSL 1 - Ubuntu 20.04.3

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a public repo to take a look? Can you share your project structure? If you detected the source of the issue, why don't you rollback to a working version?

Comment: Hi @FerranBuireu, thanks for the reply. Im sorry but i cant share my repo. So far i have tried deleting the cache, gatsby clean, downgrade npm/node versions. The strange thing is i get the error now too on the working versions before.

Answer (score 0):

Without debugging the repo it's difficult to guess. It's a bit generic but: have you tried reinstalling your dependencies?

- Remove your `package-lock.json`
- Remove your `node_modules`
- Install them again by `npm install`

---

The issue has been finally solved by updating WSL1 to WSL2.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but i tried that but didnt solve the problem.

Comment: Are you using yarn or npm?

Comment: I'm using npm but I fixed the issue by updating WSL1 to WSL2. I still think it's weird it doesn't work on WSL1. But thanks for the suggestions.